# Jest Mock + Typescript error TS2339

Tags: typescript, express, jestjs

I am building an `Express` server in `typescript` and I want to use `jest` as my testing framework.

according to examples, I saw online that if I want to mock the following class method:

```
// src/orig.ts
export class Orig {
    static testFunc() {
        return 'orig';
    }
}
```

I need to create the following file:

```
// src/__mocks__/orig.ts
export class Orig {
    static __fake: string = 'fake';
    static testFunc() {
        return Orig.__fake;
    }
}
```

with `app.js` looking like this:

```
const app = require('express')();
const { Orig } = require('./src/Orig');

app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.send(Orig.testFunc()); });

module.exports = app.listen(3000);
```

and my test file should look like this:

```
// tests/test.ts
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

import { Orig } from '../src/Orig';

jest.mock('../src/Orig');

describe('Test the mock', () => {
    test('It should return the fake string', () => {
        Orig.__fake = 'a fake string';
        return request(app).get('/').then(response => {
            expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
            expect(response.body).toEqual('a fake string');
        });
    });
});
```

My issue is that I am getting the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property '__fake' does not exist on type 'typeof Orig'
```

How can I ignore/solve this issue? or is there a better way to do mocks in my project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I used the following workaround:
instead of calling `Orig.__fake` I'm calling `Orig['__fake']`.
it's not exactly what I wanted, but it does work.